# Calculate which composite will give the lightest beam for a given force and deflection.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, material-science

A uniform rectangular-section beam of fixed width, W, unspecified depth, d, and fixed length,L, rests horizontally on two simple supports at either end of the beam. A concentrated force, F,acts vertically downwards through the centre of the beam. The deflection, $\delta$, of the loaded
point is:
$$\delta = \frac{^{3}}{4_{}^{3}}$$

Where $E_{c}$ is the modulus of the composite material used to produce the beam.

Ignoring the deflection due to self-weight, calculate which of the three composites in Table 1 will give the lightest beam for a given force and deflection.

Table 1
\begin{array}{l|c|r}
Material     &      Density / Mg m^{-3}  &      E_{c} / GPa \\
CFRP         &      1.53              &      197  \\
GFRP         &      1.85              &      37.5 \\
Steel/concrete  &   2.51              &      48.1 \\
\end{array}

Comment: I tried rearranging the equation so that i could substitute density for LWd. I also thought about rearranging the equation to derive material index as would be done in "materials selection for mechanical design" however i do not think that is the right approach.

Comment: Width and length are fixed, so the lightest beam will have the least product of density and depth. Can you work it out from here?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the $\delta$ equation, I tried introducing density to it but I'm not sure how to or whether this is the way to solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass of the beam, $M$, is equal to $$M = \rho L W d,$$ where $L$ and $W$ are the same for every beam. For a given force $F$, we can calculate the minimal width of the beam $d$ so that the deflection would not exceed $\delta$: $$d = L\left(\frac{F}{4E_cW\delta}\right)^\frac13.$$

The mass of the beam is then $$M = \rho L^2 W\left(\frac{F}{4E_cW\delta}\right)^\frac13 \propto \rho E_c^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

In arbitrary units, the $\rho E_c^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ factor is 0.263 for CFRP, 0.553 for GFRP and 0.690 for steel/concrete.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was starting to substitute for the constant variables to try to obtain so values by a brute force method, (yes, I was getting that desperate). Thanks again.